# Count occurrences of values in a specific range (Excel) (no VBA)

Tags: excel, countif

I need to count all of the occurrences of a given value from a specific range of cells (containing strings or numbers), depending on a parameter stored in another cell.

I prepared a simple Excel table as an example (see attached image): let's say I want to count all of the occurrences of the VALUE "4" for the BASE "100". The result should be: 2 (C4 + C5).

[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmpC.jpg)

I tried to use COUNTIFS and FIND functions but with no results. The former only considers exact values (so the 4 in cell C5 will be ignored) while I seem to be unable to add another condition - the BASE column - to the latter.

Fact is I need to solve this with formulas only, no programming.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use countifs with wild cards.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner thanks for your reply! I thought about that but only cells C1, C3 and C5 are considered in that case.

Comment: You are correct see my answer below.  Next time please paste the data directly in the post instead of a picture so we do not need to retype what you have already typed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$10=100)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(4,$C$2:$C$10))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of other approaches, the simpler one is just to add another column which identifies matches for you, then have your count just sum the results of that column.

[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M981h.png)

So we put the values we want to find in some reference cells, the BASE match goes in G2, and the VALUE we're looking for goes in G3.

In column D we put a formula in D2:
"=IF(B2=$G$2,IF(ISERR(SEARCH($G$3,C2)),0,1),0)"

Returns 0 if the BASE matches and we can find at least one occurent of VALUE

- B2=$G$2 - Does the BASE column match the BASE we're looking for
- ISERR(SEARCH($G$3,C2)) - Does searching for the VALUE return an error (if it does, we know that VALUE isn't there)

Copy this formula to all the cells in column D, and then you can just use a simple SUM(D:D) to count the occurences where your conditions are met.

---

The neater but slightly more complex alternative is to use an array formula to do the match finding and counting all in one formula. This would look like this:

"{=SUM(IF(B:B=$G$2,IF(ISERR(SEARCH($G$3,C:C)),0,1)))}"

Pretty much the same as the formulas in column D, but now we use B:B and C:C in place of B2 / C2 etc. and stick the SUM around the whole thing. If you finish editing with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter, that'll make it an array formula.

[Microsoft Array Formula Guidelines](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

NB: this WILL NOT count multiple occurences of 4 in a single VALUE cell.

p.s. Assuming you would want it to actually return 3 in this case (you missed the 4 in C7)